# Facebook Post (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action through angularjs facebook sdk?

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**I am using the following code in order to post to facebook page but I get this error:**

(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

I already manage permission.

This is my angularjs code

```
        var _login = function() {
             var deferred = $q.defer();
             //first check if we already have logged in
             FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                 if (response.status === 'connected') {
                     // the user is logged in and has authenticated your app
                     $rootScope.access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                     deferred.resolve(response);
                 } else {
                     // the user is logged in to Facebook, but has not authenticated your app
                     FB.login(function(response) {
                         if (response.authResponse) {
                             $rootScope.access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                             resolve(null, response, deferred);
                         } else {
                             resolve(response.error, null, deferred);
                         }
                     },{scope: 'publish_actions', return_scopes: true});
                 }
             });
             return deferred.promise;
         };

         var _post = function() {
             var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
             FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body}, function(response) {
               if (!response || response.error) {
                 alert('Can not Post');
               } else {
                 alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
               }
             },{scope: 'publish_actions, user_posts, manage_pages'});
         };

         return {
             login : _login,
             logout : _logout,
             post : _post,
         };
```

do i need to do anything else before I can post to the facebook page?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the publish_pages or publish_actions (depending on API) permission was granted, and that the access token is definitely from a user who's an admin of the page you're trying to post to?